# "Type mismatch in expression." Visual Studio 2013 with Access 2013 DB

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to do a simple "Advanced Search Button". This project is using 3 tables within 1 database. The page loads up but when I try to hit the "search button" after entering values into the textbox of website, it gives me **"Type mismatch in expression."**

Here is the code for search button;

```
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT m.musterino, m.adi, m.soyadi, m.adres, u.urunno, u.parca, u.marka, u.modelisim, u.modelno, u.fiyat, s.satisno, s.odeme, s.urun, s.garanti, s.tarih FROM musteri m, satis s, urunler u WHERE m.musterino = s.musterino AND u.urunno = s.urunno AND s.satisno = @ara"

    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("ara", TextBox1.Text)

    SqlDataSource1.Select(System.Web.UI.DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the field `s.satisno`? I bet that is not a string.

Comment: m.musterino, s.satisno and u.urunno are actually autonumbers within every single table. But at table named "satis" they are marked as number.

Edit; Those are also primary keys for every single table

Answer (score 0):

If the field `s.satisno` is of numeric type then this line is ambigous.

```
 SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("ara", TextBox1.Text)
```

You add a parameter without specifying its type. So you leave open any kind of interpretation on it and because you add a string it is possible that something doesn't go as you expect here.

I would try to be more specific on the type of the value passed for the parameter

```
 SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("ara", DbType.Int32, TextBox1.Text)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I just tried to insert "DbType.Int32" , it asked me to insert "System.Data" which I did. When I ran the application, it fires up again but typing number or text in it will lead to the same result. Also I would like to mention that, I don't want to limit my searches with only numbers. I want to search via both numbers and text where it is necessary.